# @font-face not working in firefox but fine in chrome

Tags: firefox, font-face

any ideas? here's what I'm using:

```
@font-face {
   font-family: 'Jott';
   src: url(http://stuff.saikonet.org/fonts/jott/JottFLF-Bold.ttf) format('truetype');
}
```

Comment: Are you using the same domain when you refer to the font?

Comment: as in is the site in question saikonet.org? no it is not. does that actually matter?

Comment: It does matter. See my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same-origin rule: By default, Firefox will only accept relative links. If you want to use absolute links or include fonts from different domains, you need to send these fonts with Access Control Headers. See: http://webfonts.info/wiki/index.php?title=%40font-face_support_in_Firefox

Answer (score 0):

Can that be your problem:

> In Gecko, web fonts are subject to the same domain restriction (font files must be on the same domain as the page using them), unless HTTP access controls are used to relax this restriction.
>   https://developer.mozilla.org/en/css/@font-face

When I downloaded the TTF it was working in Firefox as well.

Comment: Sorry @Kangkan - you were faster :-)